# Django : AttributeError

Tags: python, django, foreign-key-relationship

When I'm trying to retrieve data using a Foreign key from other table I'm getting the below exception:

```
'User' object has no attribute 'UserFeed_set'
```

View :

```
def user_page(request, username):
    try:
        u = User.objects.get(username=username)
    except User.DoesNotExist:
        raise Http404(u'Requested user not found.')
    feeds = u.UserFeed_set.all()
    variables = RequestContext(request, {
        'username' : username,
        'feeds' : feeds
    })
    return render_to_response('user_page.html', variables)
```

models.py:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class AllFeeds(models.Model):
    url = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=40)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.url

class UserFeed(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    myfeeds = models.ForeignKey(AllFeeds)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'%s %s'%(self.user.username,self.link.url)
```

Comment: try `userfeed_set`, otherwise post the definition for the `UserFeed` model.

Comment: This won't solve your problem (see @DanielB's comment) - but you should use [`get_object_or_404`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/http/shortcuts/#get-object-or-404) - its the shortcut that does what you are doing here the "long" way; check if a queryset returns an object othewise raise a 404.

Comment: @DanielB I have updated with the Models

Comment: @GobinathEm that code suggests my answer should be right - the `user` instance should have a `userfeed_set` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main issue here is you need to use the correct related name format, which is all lowercase; but there are some further issues with your models.

Clearning up your code, you end up with this:

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404, render

def user_page(request, username):
    u = get_object_or_404(User, username=username)
    feeds = u.userfeed_set.all()
    variables = {
        'username' : username,
        'feeds' : feeds
    }
    return render(request, 'user_page.html', variables)
```

Your models also need some editing, because you have no `self.link.url`:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class AllFeeds(models.Model):
    url = models.URLField(unique=True, max_length=40)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return unicode(self.url)

class UserFeed(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    myfeeds = models.ForeignKey(AllFeeds)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return unicode('{0} {1}'.format(self.user.username, self.myfeeds.url))
```

Comment: While you're cleaning, instead of referencing `User` you should use `settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL` for `ForeignKey`s and [`django.contrib.auth.get_user_model`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#django.contrib.auth.get_user_model) when referencing the object directly.

Answer (score 1):

If you haven't a [`related_name`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name) on the `ForeignKey` field of the `UserFeed` model, it should be a accessible as `user.userfeed_set`. (The default name is `model.__name__.lower() + "_set"`).

If you have set the `releated_name`, the method will be called whatever you named gave as the value.

Answer (score 0):

as I know, if you have the two models using manytomany relation, you can use u.userfeed_set.all(), but as u said, your models are using one-to-one relation